# Any way to parse NSKeyedArchiver on Android / Java?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, nskeyedarchiver

I've got some files saved from an iOS app using a NSKeyedArchiver but now I need to be able to read and write to this from an Android utility? Is there any Java library out there that deals with binary plists created using 'NSKeyedArchiver'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following library to read and write plist's in java. From what I've read it should be able to handle the multiple formats for a plist (Binary, XML, ASCII).

[Property List Library](http://sourceforge.net/p/plist/home/synopsis/)

As for decoding `NSKeyedArchiver`, I am not aware of any libraries out there that can achieve this.